# Option for Snappy ProductIO module to read the bands of tiff image

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, tiff

In the  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cZidf9taJ8) I followed, they read the bands of the tiff image using the ESA Snappy module. Like this:

[image: tutorial]

But I failed to install this module to my Python 3.8 environment. Instead, I tried using a different package to read the bands of the 31-band tiff image.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mtp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import earthpy.plot as ep
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image

%matplotlib inline

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 89

#setting the path for image
S1_S2_stack = 'S1_S2_stack.tif'

#path to training and validation data
training_points = 'testing.shp'
validation_points = 'training.shp'

colors = dict ((
    (0, (0,76,153,255)),  #wheat
    (1, (0,153,0,255)),   #corn
    (2, (255,0,0,255)),   #other
    (3, (255,153,51,255)),
    (4, (255,255,0,255))
    
))

for k in colors:
    v = colors [k]
    _v = [_v / 255.0 for _v in v]
    colors[k] = _v
    
index_colors = [colors[key] if key in colors else (1,1,1,0) for key in range (0,5)]
cmap = plt.matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(index_colors, 'Classification', 5)

src = rasterio.open(S1_S2_stack)
src1 = src.read(S1_S2_stack)
bands = list (src1.tags())
```

And when I run the last section it throws me an error which says:

```
IndexError: band index S out of range (not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31))
```

So I'll appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is not a band index.

```py
S1_S2_stack = 'S1_S2_stack.tif'
src = rasterio.open(S1_S2_stack)
src1 = src.read(S1_S2_stack)      # Error: sending a name instead of an index
```

Here's what we know about [the read method](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/cb44c002bde27e93414735ecf124829010cf7248/rasterio/_io.pyx#L396):

```py
def read(indexes=None, ...)
"""
indexes : int or list, optional
    If `indexes` is a list, the result is a 3D array, but is
    a 2D array if it is a band index number.
"""
```

It reads the bands by their indexes, which are the first parameter and should be either an integer or a list of integers. If `None` it [returns all](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/cb44c002bde27e93414735ecf124829010cf7248/rasterio/_io.pyx#L474) the bands. Therefore the code should be something like

```py
src1 = src.read()            # Read all bands together
```

or

```py
index = 0                    # set the band to read
assert 1 <= index <= src.count    # make sure the index does not exceed the number of bands
src1 = src.read(index)       # read the band
```

or

```py
indexes = [1,2,3]
src1 = src.read(indexes)     # read some of the bands
```